# jQTouch: How to embed  YouTube video?

Tags: html, jqtouch, html5-video

I am trying to embed a YouTube video into a page of a jQTouch mobile app.

I tried using the "embed" code from YouTube and it worked on my desktop browser (Chrome), but not on my iPod Touch browser (Safari).

I then tried using the HTML5 video tag, and still got nothing.

How exactly can I embed a YouTube video into a jQTouch app?

I have seen embedded YouTube videos from non-jQTouch pages (e.g. www.squidoo.com/sqlitehammer) which played fine on the iPod Touch.

Comment: What does your embed code look like?

Comment: <video id="movie" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx" width="320" height="426" controls>
    your browser does not support the video tag
    </video>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code block as part of a jqtouch app (running from the web), which launches the YouTube app as expected when tested on a mobile device:

```
    <div id="m_intro1" class="current">
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Page Heading</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <object width="320" height="320">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{your_movie_id_goes_here}?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{your_movie_id_goes_here}?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="320" />
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you the Railscasts guy? If so, your videos are awesome! If not, you could still lie that you are.

Comment: Bingo, bango, bongo! It worked. Thanks Ryan. (But when I tried to play the video, it said that the format wasn't supported). Time for another stackoverflow qvestion.

Comment: can you put the link for the website

Comment: sure - it's harmonytoc.com Username = demo, password = harmony