# jQTouch App: iPod: embedded YouTube video - format not supported

Tags: jqtouch, ipod-touch, video-encoding, embedded-video

I finally got my [jQTouch/iPod web app embedding a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231002/jqtouch-how-to-embed-youtube-video). Thanks to [Ryan Bates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61605/ryan-bates). 
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <object width="320" height="320">
       <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/DZSZIfhzc3A?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" />
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
       <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
       <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/DZSZIfhzc3A?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="320" />
    </object>
</div>
```

The problem is that even though the video displays fine, and fires up the YouTube player fine, I get a message that says that the format is not supported.

What do I have to do to get the right format for the iPod Touch to play, or to get a player that works on the iPod Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash man you can`t use flash. Use the HTML5 embed code. I am not sure you tube has one. If it does not look into www.vimeo.com